# N-число нажатий на кнопку открывают другое активити

Tags: android, button, android-on-click

Я хочу сделать пасхалку, но не знаю как сделать само событие и настроить обработчик так, чтобы он открывал активити после N-числа нажатий, подскажите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2):

```
int n = 5;

int countClicks = 0

public void onClick(View view){

    count++;
    if(count == n){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AnotherActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    count = 0;

}
```

Псевдокод на коленке, но идей на самые разные вкус и цвет.

Можете вообще использовать генератор случайных чисел на какой-то незаметный элемент, и проверять его на `if(n % 10 == 0){some code};`

Все зависит от вашей фантазии, вопрос крайне не корректен.

Comment: Не помогло, if(n % 10 == 0){some code}; это вообще не работает.